# Generating PHP classes based on XSD file

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I've got an XSD file from which I need to extract the `name` attribute value from the `xs:element` element (which contains a PHP class name).

How can I do that?

Here is the XSD file:

```
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" targetNamespace="DTS"
    xmlns:mstns="DTS"
    xmlns="DTS"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="DtsDiscountPaxType">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="OfficeCd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- Mandatory -->
                <!-- Particular office code on which the discounts are available -->
                <xs:element name="MarketCd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- Mandatory -->
                <!-- Particular market code on which the discounts are available -->
                <xs:element name="AgentId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- Mandatory -->
                <xs:element name="Language" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- Mandatory -->
                <xs:element name="CruiseID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- Optional -->
                <xs:element name="BookingChannel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <!-- Allows to search with that cruise id -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="DtsDiscountPaxType" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm trying to use xsd2php that I found on github. I would also appreciate if you could explain me or link me something to understand how can i use xsd2php.

Comment: You will need to share more about the problem, is this a standard xsd you are using (for some system)?  Also what have you found out so far about this?

Comment: i started working with xsd recently, i will add the xsd code up above. I find out, on github, xsd2php and i'm attempting to use it (i'm not so familiar with github too). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: And what do you mean by "get php classes"? Are you referring to the `name` attribute of the `xs:element` element?

Comment: DocRoot, exactly, I'm sorry to explain myself so badly